# Php how to get newest browser version

Tags: php, browser, version

I need to do a php script, that warns users if their browser is not the newest version.
I know, that in php you can get the browser version with `get_browser()`. But how could i get the newest version... Is there any site, that would provide such information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that api: http://fresh-browsers.com/export/browsers.json it generetes the latest versions of the browsers using JSON or if you want XML: http://fresh-browsers.com/export/browsers.xml

Answer (score 1):

These sites have an overview with browser versions:
http://browsehappy.com/
http://fresh-browsers.com/

maybe with some creativity and cUrl you could extract those numbers and put them in version_compare.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php

But I might suggest that you create your website for a few certain browser versions, and then check hard-coded if the current version will do. This to prevent people from seeing a message of an outdated browser, while it might not be even needed to view your site in the newest version pf that browser.